# IE7 Bot window.location.href object expected error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7

So Microsoft has been running IE7 browsers as bots because even though *YOU* should upgrade why not run an IE7 bot, right? >__> So any way in my JavaScript error log I keep getting an obnoxious error that I can't figure out. I've run IE7/XP 64 in a virtual machine and can't reproduce the error...

```
function page()
{
 var a = decodeURI(window.location.href).split(path,2);
 var b = a[1].split(section()+'/',2);
 return b[1];
}

function section()
{
 var a = decodeURI(window.location.href).split(path,2);
 var b = a[1].split('/',2);
 return b[0];
}
```

The error message...

> Object expected

...which occurs on the last line of the function: `}`. Yeah, *that* helps.

So since I don't run IE7 bots could someone please give me some insight in to how to address this issue so their bot stops spawning needless errors?

Comment: When you attempt to replicate, what values are you using? What is `section()`? You could attempt to log all the values in that function so you see exactly what the bot is seeing, `if IE7 log values`

Comment: section would be .com/section/ ('section') and page would be anything after the / after the section (e.g. .com/section/this/is/a/page page would be 'is/a/page page'). Since the IE7 bot returns a worthless line and I can't reproduce it anywhere myself I can't figure out what object isn't set, maybe the `b[1]` for the `return`?